# Why am I getting a NullPointerException for strokeWeight() in Processing.py?

Tags: python, nullpointerexception, processing

A quick disclaimer: I'm a bit of a newbie, so this issue might be just me not seeing the obvious, but basically when I run

```
def setup():
    size(400,400)

def test():
    strokeWeight(5)
    circle(100, 100, 100)

test()
```

in Processing I get the following error:

```
processing.app.SketchException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at processing.core.PApplet.strokeWeight(PApplet.java:14431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:188)
    at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:206)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:497)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:501)
    at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:141)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx58.test$2(sketch_210426a.pyde:6)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx58.call_function(sketch_210426a.pyde)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:171)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:139)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:413)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx58.f$0(sketch_210426a.pyde:1)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx58.call_function(sketch_210426a.pyde)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:171)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1614)
    at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java:1658)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx57.f$0(/var/folders/vf/3zy00t252_372n6n1n060tc00000gn/T/sketch_210426a6112183873956099370/sketch_210426a.pyde:96)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx57.call_function(/var/folders/vf/3zy00t252_372n6n1n060tc00000gn/T/sketch_210426a6112183873956099370/sketch_210426a.pyde)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:171)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1614)
    at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java:1658)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java:276)
    at jycessing.PAppletJythonDriver.processSketch(Unknown Source)
    at jycessing.PAppletJythonDriver.findSketchMethods(Unknown Source)
    at jycessing.Runner.runSketchBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.lambda$startSketch$3(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.convertPythonSketchError(Unknown Source)
    at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.lambda$startSketch$3(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Interestingly enough, I am only returned the error when any one of Processing's built in functions (such as `setup()`, `draw()` or `mouseClicked`) is defined as well, so if I ran:

```
def why_arent_you_working():
    print("please")
    
def test():
    strokeWeight(5)
    circle(100, 100, 100)
    
test()
why_arent_you_working()
```

it would work for some reason.

I've tried 10 diffrent threads concerning `NullPointerException` but I just can't seem to find what I did wrong. As I've prefaced this post, I am a newbie, so its probably some stupid oversight of mine but it would be great if someone helped me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a result of "mixing active and static modes". Active mode is when you use `setup()` and/or `draw()`, and static mode is when you don't. Basically, if you're using `setup()`, you can't call any functions outside of an indentation (or a variable definition). The standard way to draw a circle on the screen is like this:

```
def setup():
    size(400,400)

def draw():
    strokeWeight(5)
    circle(100, 100, 100)
```

`draw()` is called just like `setup()` is: it's automatically called without you explicitly calling it anywhere.

Keep in mind that `draw()` is a loop, so it will run continuously until `noLoop()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable what you're doing is creating something that points towards that variable. I.e when we create a variable x = 5. `x` is just a reference that points towards the number `5`.

`NullPointerException` occurs when you're pointing at something that is `Null`. I'm not all too familiar with the strokeWeight method so I can't tell you exactly but I can try to help more if you add a tiny bit more code for me.

In the log files (The second part you've coded in) you can click the line number and it will take you to which part of a method the error is coming from.

So below it tells us that the `NullPointerException` is coming from somewhere called `processing.core.PApplet.strokeWeight` in line 14431. If you could click the number and copy the method into your original post I can try help a little more from there.

`processing.app.SketchException: java.lang.NullPointerException at processing.core.PApplet.strokeWeight(PApplet.java:14431)`

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm not quite sure what you mean. I've clicked on the number but it doesn’t take me anywhere. Here's a screenshot: https://ibb.co/F7vbPzh. I'm also not sure where to click, somewhere in the console? I'm working in Python Processing and again, thanks

Comment: Sorry I assumed your editor would have supported it my bad! What is the aim of this code are you trying to draw a circle? And also have you imported the processing package?

Comment: No, its fine. The circle() function is a built in function within Processing and it takes parameters such as height, width and radius to draw a circle when called. I have not imported any package that I am aware of.